# pyvirtualdisplay on WSL2 ubuntu not loading

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, pyvirtualdisplay

I am trying to run this pyvirtualdisplay, my prof just gave me a doc without any installation tutorials. I don't even know if it works on wsl.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiIfU.png)

the virtual_display.start() is just keeps loading.

I can not find any solutions and is it better doing on windows?